# 0-2v to 0-10v amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

tl;dr:   I want to understand op-amps better!  How do I choose the magnitude of resistors?  1k, 10k, 100k, etc..  I made a schematic to play with an In-amp to create a gain of 5.
What other considerations should I implement in a real world circuit?

-

I'm trying to learn how to use op-amps to provide a gain of Av=5
Eventually I would like to apply this knowledge to the use of strain gages in a Wheatstone configuration.  That's a later thing :)

For now, I'm diving into it by creating a instrumentation amplifier with a gain of 5.  I like this approach because as I understand it, it is a more robust solution to boosting a signal for a variety of reasons.  Not to mention the gain is easily adjusted, which I may be interested in using a digital potentiometer in that location for just that reason.

This is what I have came up with so far in ltspice:
[image]

This yields what I want:

[image]

The frequency is not very relevant in my situation, the signal won't be changing very much over the course of 1 second.

So my question to you guys,

1. Why do I choose resistors in the realm of 1k?  Why not 10k? or 100k?
2. How can I add some basic noise filtering?
3. Do you see any issues that may occur in applying the circuit above to real life?

I apologize for my lack of knowledge and terminology if I butchered anything!  Thank you for any time you can lend me, I do circuits by hobby and want to understand more of the analog elements.

Comment: Are you planning on using an instrumentation amp IC (all two or three op amps in one IC) or constructing a discrete in amp out of three op amp ICs? (Hint: you should use the former.)

Comment: I hadn't thought of it!  That's fantastic that those are offered.  I would gladly use an IC for the in-amp.  I've already found a few IC's that looks like they would work a treat.  This makes things almost too easy..!! :)

Comment: Your simulation does not match your schematic (gain is actually -5). You should consider power supply voltages, common mode input range and output swings or you may run into issues when you actually build the circuit. There is no advantage that I can see to a three amplifier circuit in this case compared to a single non-inverting amplifier (assuming you actually want a gain of +5) as you don't really care about CMRR.

Comment: See, for example [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf) datasheet and study figures 20~23.

Comment: I was thinking I would build it with 12v power supply referencing ground.  Which doesn't allow for a great approach to the 0v rail but that's okay for my application, I'm not looking at the signal when it's near 0v
Thank you very much for these answers! (I had slightly modified the circuit earlier to account for the negative gain, I must have not screen shot the correct one)

I guess I could just do it right and float a 24v power supply half way...   Ooh there's so many design decisions one can ponder

Comment: Am I the only one who sees positive feedback in the final output stage?

Comment: @Marla I see it as well. X1_1 needs to have V+ and V- reversed or it will latch up.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you choose too low valued resistors, they would draw too much current and dissipate too much, which isn't needed. (And when they draw really too much current, the may overdrive the OpAmps as well and/or damage it).
   If you choose too high valued resistors, your circuit may be prone to external noise. And next to that, the OpAmp draws a small input current as well. With too big resistors, those currents influence the circuit too much.
   Depending on the voltage of the OpAmps you pick the resistors.
2. I'd advise to start reading about RC filters and apply them.
3. Leaving that to others. I'm not that experienced applying them.

Comment: Do the resistors themselves generate noise, and more resistance corresponds to more noise?

Comment: Although the answer is yes, neglecting their noise, big (ideal) resistors still make the circuit very sensitiy. "inject some noise" by adding a voltage source (1Vpp sine) and connect it with e.g. 10M to the negative input terminal of one of the opamps. Simulate with your current set up and then change the 1-10k resistors to 1M-10M resistors.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, Johnson-Nyquist (thermal) noise is directly proportional to the resistance of the resistor. It's only really a problem in high precision circuits though, as far as I know.

Comment: @Hearth and Huisman Thanks: I wondered about that because the OP mentioned noise filtering, and I thought that if the circuit added more noise because of using large-value resistors that would be relevant. Although at the ~1 Hz signals they suggest, perhaps not.

Answer (score 1):

2. Noise is just a signal you haven't understood yet...
   It's pretty typical to filter out signals that might get in the way of making a robust measurement of your sensor outputs. You'll get a better measurement if you can remove signals you wont be able to measure accurately or don't care about.

For example:

- Most systems will sample vout with an ADC at a fixed frequency. Any signals that have a frequency higher than 1/2 of that frequency are very hard to understand with that ADC and conventional methods, so it's pretty typical to ensure that the amplifier acts as a low pass filter to remove most of the frequency content above 1/2 the sampling frequency (the Nyquist limit) (In this case signal that would be hard to understand is filtered out of the output waveform leaving only the signals that can be well measured for future assessment.)
- Many indoor systems will measure 50/60Hz noise from the AC power systems around them. If this noise is enough to saturate your sensor systems, you might want a band stop filter to remove it. You might also see a high pass filter to filter this out if you don't care about the DC offset from your sensor. (In this case an understood signal is being filtered out. If it's small enough it will be easier to filter out these signals in software later.)

Answer (score 0):

High value resistors easily introduce high phase shifts into the negative-feedback loop, causing peaking, ringing, and oscillation.

For fun, attach 1,000pF or 10,000pF to the inverting ( -Vin ) pin of just about any opamp circuit.